# Facebook Graph: do you need a token now?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Until a couple of days ago I was able to access the Facebook Graph data of any page through the browser by specifying its id like this:

http://graph.facebook.com/113335124914

now it's not possible anymore? do you need an access token?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, recently a change has been made and it seems that you now require access tokens for calling the graph API as you are.

I am not sure what information you were using from the graph request but you can still call the graph API like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.facebook.com/113335124914%27
```

Or another option:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.facebook.com/113335124914&format=json
```

Comment: Thanks! give the id, I would like to get page name and page category. Can I still do that without using a token?

Comment: Hi, my question is much related to the problem above. I use the second option but now I'd like to echo the "Like_count". Could you please take a look at my code cause it doesn't work... Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962875/call-facebook-api-to-echo-like-count-doesnt-work

Comment: I don't know if getting the name and cover picture URL is still possible.