# Call Facebook API to echo like count doesn't work

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to display the number of likes for my Facebook page on my website. The previous method I used isn't working anymore since a couple of days.

When I call the Facebook graph API like this:
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.facebook.com/549585444&format=json

It gives me the following output (fictional example):

```
[{"url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/549585444","normalized_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/549585444","share_count":0,"like_count":122,"comment_count":0,"total_count":122,"click_count":0,"comments_fbid":null,"commentsbox_count":0}]
```

Now I like to echo the like count:

```
<?php
    $fb_page = "549585444"; 
    $url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.facebook.com/".$fb_page."&format=json";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $json_returned = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);
    $json_returned = json_decode($json_returned, true);
    echo $json_returned['like_count'];
?>
```

But the number doesn't appear. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the JSON output, the answer is wrapped in an array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(33) "http://www.facebook.com/549585444"
    ["normalized_url"]=>
    string(33) "http://www.facebook.com/549585444"
    ["share_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["like_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["comment_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["total_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["click_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["comments_fbid"]=>
    NULL
    ["commentsbox_count"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

To get the number output, you'll have to get the first item in the array by changing this row:

```
echo $json_returned['like_count'];
```

To this:

```
echo $json_returned[0]['like_count'];
```